# Api сервис возвращает ошибку параметра

Tags: php, api

```
function ApiInit($method, $params=null)
{
    $key = $_GET['API_KEY_PUBLIC'];
    $secret = $_GET['API_KEY']; 
    $time = date('y', time() - date('Z'));
    $time0 = date('d', time() - date('Z'));     
    $time1 = date('H', time() - date('Z'));
    $time2 = date('i', time() - date('Z'));
    $time3 = date('s', time() - date('Z'));
    $nonce=$time.$time0.$time1.$time2.$time3;
    $post = [
        'method' => $method,
        'params' => $params,
        'nonce' => $nonce
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://yobit.net/tapi/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'key: ' . $key,
        'sign: ' . hash_hmac('SHA512', null, $secret)
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($res);
    if(!$res) {
        $error = curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')';
        echo $error;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $j_res = json_decode($res);
    return $j_res;
}
ApiInit('Trade','&pair='.$new_nopc.'&type=buy&rate='.$Sell*1.2.'&amount=1');
```

Ошибка:{"success":0,"error":"invalid pair"}

Comment: м.б. Вам лучше спросить у поставщика api ?

Comment: Они не отвечают

Comment: Вы думаете, что если их спросим мы, то нам то уж точно ответят? Читайте документацию по сервису

Comment: Можете не писать сюда советы типа : "Иди читай документацию".